# Will updating my graphics card make it support DirectX 11?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, gpu

I am new to this community so if I have posted this in the wrong community please tell me the correct one so that I can post it where I can get help.

My Graphics Card currently supports DirectX 10.1(that is what DDI in DirectX Diagnostic Tool says). I want to run Unreal Engine 4.7.2 on my computer. But when I run it, it shows this message:[Unreal Engine Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5VpI.png)

Which says A D3D11-compatible GPU (Feature Level 11.0, Shader Model 5.0) is required to run the engine.
As far as I can understand this means that my GPU must support DirectX 11. Now in my computer DirectX 11 is installed (most probably by the Epic Games Installer) but my GPU doesn't use it (you can see it in the picture links below given). So my question is that will updating my graphics card driver make it support DirectX 11?If yes, then how to do it?
Images:
[DirectX Diagnostic Tool System Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wJ5k.png),
[DirectX Diagnostic Tool Display Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBR3k.png)

Regards,
Jishnu

Comment: Drivers can't change hardware features.

Comment: No reason to _not_ keep your graphics driver up to date, though.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Seems like its time to get this good old computer to the shop and install new hardware.